# How to remove the duplicate header of a contact form in Joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a menu that points to a native joomla contact form.

My problem is that I can't remove the double "`Contact`" and "`Contact Form`" headings from my page.
I don't know if it is related but my website has multi-language support.

See below :

[image]

I only want that my menu points directly to the form without heading.
Can you help me with this ?

---

**EDIT :**

Thanks to the answer of Simonyan Hayk, I managed to remove the second `Contact Form`. However there was still the first one `Contact`. Finally I found another similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://geekflare.com/remove-contact-title-in-contact-form-in-joomla/) and I summarised it below :

1. Login into Joomla Admin
2. Click on Extension >> Language Manager
3. Click on Overrides
4. Click on New
5. Enter following in Language Constant : `COM_CONTACT_DETAILS`
6. Click on Save and close
7. Repeat steps 1 to 6 for each language of the website (with the dropdown menu filter on the left)

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable page heading by editing menu item. Go to "Page display" tab and turn off "Show Page Heading" or you can customize your contact-page by editing "contact display options".

Comment: I tried both but it didn't work, I still have the duplicate header.

Comment: try to clean website cache from admin panel and refresh the site.

Comment: thanks for you help, But I don't have anything in my cache

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Remove Header](http://www.thecoderscorner.com/team-blog/joomla-cms/24-remove-duplicate-contact-heading-joomla) . Remove that second header from language overrides.